# How to save user filter input after redirecting to detail site and going back again

Tags: php, redirect, get

So I have set up a simple php site where a user can filter the content of a table. Included is also a detail link with every entry that redirects the user to a site which displays only the details of the used entry. The detail site basically only displays the specific info and one button which lets the user go back to the original website.

My problem is that I want to save the users filter input when forwarding to the detail site and also when he is clicking the link to go back to the original website. Ideally I would like to do it with `$_GET` if that is possible.

Here is my **index.php**:

index.php:

```
    <h1>Benutzerdaten anzeigen</h1>
    <div class="filter">
        <label class="labelf">Filtern:</label>


        <input id="filterfeld" name='filterfeld' onkeyup="filterRows()" value =<?php echo $_GET['filterfeld']; ?>>
        <button id="reset" class="reset" value="Reset" onclick="window.location.reload(true)">RESET</button>

    </div>
    <?php
    $servername = "localhost";
    $username = "root";
    $username = "root";
    $password = "";
    $dbname = "php13";
    $filter_value = isset($_GET['filterfeld']) ? $_GET['filterfeld'] : "";




    // Create connection
    $conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
    // Check connection
    if ($conn->connect_error) {
        die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
    }

    $sql = "SELECT * FROM user";
    $result = $conn->query($sql);

    if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
        echo "<table align='center' id='ftable' class='ftable'><tr><th>ID</th><th>Vorname</th><th>Nachname</th><th>E-Mail</th><th>Telefon</th><th>Geburtsdatum</th><th>Straße</th><th>Details</th></tr>";
        // output data of each row
        while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {

            echo "<td></td><tr><td>" . $row["id"] . "</td><td>" . $row["firstname"] . "</td><td>" . $row["lastname"] . "</td>
    <td>" . $row["email"] . "</td><td>" . $row["phone"] . "</td><td>" . $row["birthdate"] . "</td><td>" . $row["street"] . "</td><td><a href='singleentry.php?id=" .$row["id"]."&filterfeld=". $filter_value . "' class='details'>Details</a></td></tr>";
        }
        echo "</table>";
    } else {
        echo "0 results";
    }
    $conn->close();
    ?>

</form>
```

back button in the detail site **singleentry.php**:

```
<p align="center"><a href='index.php?filterfeld="<?php echo $_GET['filterfeld']?>"'><button>Zurück</button></a></p>
```

*filtering with js:*

```
    var input, filter, table, tr, td, cell, i, j;
    input = document.getElementById("filterfeld");
    filter = input.value.toUpperCase();
    table = document.getElementById("ftable");
    tr = table.getElementsByTagName("tr");

        for (i = 1; i < tr.length; i++) {
            tr[i].style.display = "none";
            td = tr[i].getElementsByTagName("td");
            for (var j = 0; j < td.length; j++) {
                cell = tr[i].getElementsByTagName("td")[j];
                if (cell) {
                    if (cell.innerHTML.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1) {
                        tr[i].style.display = "";

                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
}
```

Currently I have to refresh the original page with the filtertext to be able to pass it on to the detail site, which is not ideal. It should normally just refresh the site, but already with the previous filtering text and data.

Please ask if anything is unclear! 
Thanks already for any help!

Answer (score -1):

So y9ou want to remember "state" of a page.

You have many options, but staying close to what you posted:

Post the filteroptions to the other site, and include them when they go back. You will end up with a post to the other site with encoded filteroptions in (GET or POST). 
Suppose you post to details.php

GET: http://othersite.com/details.php?filter1=23&filter2=whatever

Important: You MUST change the action of the form to include the new filteroptions (that only existed in javascript), or (easier) change a hidden formelement to contain the options.

On details.php you must make the back-button contain the filteroptions it received earlier.